# nodejs get current url in config file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use express framework and here is my app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();        
var config = require('./config.js')(app, express); // I include config.js here

var models = {};                                                       
models.item = require('./models/item')(app.mongoose, app).model;

require('./routes')(app, models);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

As you can see I include config.js file on 3 line. Here is my config.js file:

```
module.exports = function(app, express){
    var config = this;

    //generic config
    app.configure(function(){           
        app.set('CURRENT_URL', '***'); // I don't know how to get current URL here
        app.use(express.bodyParser());
        app.use(express.cookieParser());
        app.use(express.session({ secret: 'topsecret' }));     
        app.use(express.methodOverride());
        app.use(app.router);
        app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
    });

    app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));

    return config;
};
```

On 6 line I set CURRENT_URL to '***'. How to detect current URL in this place?

Comment: what do you mean by current url?

Comment: For example http://localhost:3000/items/get_all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a middleware to set the current url.

```
app.use(setCurrentUrl);

function setCurrentUrl(req, res, next) {
    app.set('CURRENT_URL', req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl);
    next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you quite understand what `configure` does, `configure` is only called **once** when you start your application and it is to define **configuration** hence the word **configure**

I think that you think this function get's called on every request which it does **not**. The only urls you can get from that function are is the file name and the process location.

ie.

```
__dirname;
process.cwd();
```

Maybe you want `app.use`

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I thought that it got called on every request